# Extend current automapper instance with new mapper configurations

Tags: c#, singleton, asp.net5, automapper-10

I am using AutoMapper 10.1.1 in my .net5 application.
In the startup of the project I have configured all my maps and then created mapper from the Mapper Configuration, something like:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<S,D>()....
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Now I want to add a mapping at runtime to the existing mapper object. **I can use the mapper object created above across application**. So now I want to add a new configuration to that object. Something like:

```
var config2 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<S,D>()....
});
mapper.Extend(config2);
```

Is there any way to do this, if no what workaround I can do?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#profile-instances

Comment: I forgot to add that I also want dependency injection in that class where I want to extend the mapper which is not possible with profiles as far as I know. @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core